# Map Curl Effect

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I want to make map curl effect just like iPhone 5 map. 
And many apps on App store have already this feature but I can't find any good source to implement it. Please help me. It should start with curled corner that when touching it expand to half of the screen.
Curled corner is not image.

Just look at this reference.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d51z86xtb93exc2/yRnbgpz6cc

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For questions like this I like to start out on Github and search for code that can do what I want. A Quick search ( https://github.com/search?q=page+curl&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=Objective-C ) reveals projects like https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl and many more.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe XBPageCurl can help you:

https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl/downloads

Comment: This one works well but it reimplements all the stuff that is in UIPageViewController (the curl effect itself) :/ It's a pity that there does not seem to be a way to reuse most of the UIPageViewController and customise it to get a *HALF* modal curl :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is something like this:

```
SampleViewController *sampleView =  [SampleViewController new];
[sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[self presentViewController:sampleView animated:YES completion:^void(){}];
```

Comment: This is just for half curl. Do you know how to make curled corner just like the first image?

Comment: I think you basically have to start and pause the animation to get the curled corner.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please leave some code please?

Comment: I can't think of code off of the top of my head for this, sorry. I do think you have to set up an animation and use layers, but I'm not positive.

Answer (score -1):

It's the UIPageViewController of Apple.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

I already tried it and it's working.

Comment: The UIPageViewController can provide page curls but you can't really make a HALF curl as you would get it using UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl.

Comment: @yonel I haven't tried UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl so I do not know what it looks like. Whatever is that, I've tried UIPageViewController and it worked for me. The curl effect of UIPageViewController follows the finger of the user as he/she turn the page to previous/next.